# How to get id and type in php foreach loop and send to server via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i have 2 files index.php and changeLikeDislike.php. I think the issue is where javascript is trying to get the type and id but I do not know how I would go about that. My javascript function is being called in the foreach->li->divs. It was working before like this: `data: dataString,` but I added schoolId into data of ajax as well so it's like this now `data: {dataString:dataString, schoolId:schoolId},`

index.php

```
<?php
                $last_id = 0;
                foreach ($list as $rs) {
                    $last_id = $rs['id']; // keep the last id for the paging
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <div style="width:100%; color:#000;">
                            <?php echo '<div class="product_like thumb-div"><img src="like.png" class="rating-image " onclick=changeLikeDislike("like","'.$rs['id'].'")> <br><span id="product_like_'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['pLike'].'</span></div>';?>
                            <?php echo '<div class="product_dislike"><img src="dislike.png" class="rating-image" onclick=changeLikeDislike("dislike","'.$rs['id'].'")><br> <span id="product_dislike_'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['pDislike'].'</span></div>';?>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
//begin like and dislike
function changeLikeDislike(type,id){
  var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&type=' + type;
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "changeLikeDislike.php",
  data: {dataString:dataString, schoolId:schoolId},
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
           if(result){
                console.log('working');
          }
    }
  });//end ajax
}
```

schoolId works in data but not dataString in ajax How would i go about grabbing those. My php file for reference:

```
//checks if school page id was brought and stores into variable
if (isset($_POST['schoolId'])) {
    $schoolIdFinal =  $_POST['schoolId'];
}else {
    echo "nope";
}
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $type =  $_POST['type'];
}else {
    echo "nope type";
}
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id =  $_POST['id'];
}else {
    echo "nope id";
}
```

my page is echoing out "nope type nope id"

Comment: Where is `schoolId` defined in your javascript?

Comment: that is defined in a different area of the page, the header.php which I include. schoolIs does work I already tested that I just do not know why my dataString is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
data: {dataString:dataString, schoolId:schoolId},
```

to

```
data: {type:type, id:id, schoolId:schoolId},
```

to match the params to your PHP script.

`data` can either be a query string (like your `dataString`) OR a json struct (like `{type:type, id:id, schoolId:schoolId}`).

See the documentation of `jQuery.ajax()`:
"The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}."

see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: That's great,@user4589398! If my answer solved the problem, you can accept it so that other users can rapidly find the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the data bracket. change

```
data: {dataString:dataString, schoolId:schoolId}
```

to

```
data: {dataString:'dataString', schoolId:'schoolId'}
```

next time do a print_r of $_REQUEST or $_POST to see what fields are being recognized and in this case it looks like its not detecting anything.

Comment: hmm that does not seem to fix the issue. Also In my console my var schoolId does come up with a value but dataString says 'dataString is not defined'

Comment: then that means that dataString is not defined. check to see why its not defined.